# Angularjs website slow response on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My website is built using angularjs. There are few functions needs to be performed in the front end. This does not make any problem in desktop. But in mobile the page response is slow, (i.e.) say when I click on the 'about us' page the device is waiting for the response but as a user I don't know what's going on. After say 3-5 seconds the page loads.

So I thought of using the nganimate during the page enter and leave. Still only when the page changes the animation works. Is there a way to fade out the page as soon as the user click a link and then fade in the new page? Like is there a way to animate from the '$routeChangeSuccess' for page leaving and enter or any other better way??

Comment: Do you have different `view` for that page ?

Comment: Yes. All the pages are in different views.

Comment: Once user clicks on 'about us', he should be navigated to that `view`. There is no way you will get delay in this process. Can you share the relevant code ?

Comment: Can't guess the issue..without looking at code..Its like puzzle..